# How to insert a new item into IEnumerable<class>

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a class that contains that:

```
public class BigClass
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public class SegmentClass1
        {
            public string atribb1 { get; set; }
            public string attrib2 { get; set; }
            public DateTime attrib3 { get; set; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<SegmentClass1> Segments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I add some values into this IEnumerable:
I try to do this way:

```
private static nameSpace.BigClass.Class1 Request(JObject request)
{
    nameSpace.BigClass.Class1 bigRequest = new BigClass.Class1();
    bigRequest.Segments = new List<BigClass.Class1.SegmentClass1>();
    foreach (var item in bigRequest.Segments)
    {
        item.atrrib1 = request.GetValue("attrib3").Value<DateTime>();
        item.attrib2 = request.GetValue("attrib2").Value<string>();
        item.attrib3 = request.GetValue("attrib1").Value<string>();
    }
    return bigRequest;
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: You can't insert items into an IEnumerable. That's the point of the interface. You can insert into a List though, but you have to tell the compiler that the object is actually a List.

Comment: IEnumerable is only readable

Comment: *I try to do this way:* Where? You seem to loop the `Segments` but never tried to Add one!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel OP is tring to update some properties of each item

Comment: I think he's trying to create a new item in the enumerable for every item in the `request`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @gunr2171 said, you can't insert into an IEnumerable, but you can insert into a list.

Simply create your list as a variable, insert your data in it, and then assign it to the Segments property.

```
private static nameSpace.BigClass.Class1 Request(JObject request)
{
  nameSpace.BigClass.Class1 bigRequest = new BigClass.Class1();
  var internalList = new List<BigClass.Class1.SegmentClass1>();
  internalList.Add(new SegmentClass1
        {
            attrib1 = request.GetValue("attrib1").Value<DateTime>(),
            attrib2 = request.GetValue("attrib2").Value<string>(),
            attrib3 = request.GetValue("attrib3").Value<string>()
        });
  bigRequest.Segments = internalList;
  return bigRequest
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert into an `IEnumerable<>`. The only thing it can do is getting enumerated (for example by using a `foreach`).

There are multiple collection classes that implement `IEnumerable<>` as well as provide means of inserting. `List<>` and `Collection<>` come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable doesn't have an Add() method on it. The purpose of IEnumerable is for items that can be enumerated (looped) over. Some concrete implementations of IEnumerable (List for example) have an Add() method, and some do not.

You can change your Segments property to IList if you need to add items to it.